# Keyboard shortcut for inserting new slide

Tags: libreoffice-impress

Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to create a new slide in LibreOffice Impress? I would configure my own shortcut via `Tools` > `Customize` > `Keyboard` but I can't find the appropriate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does give you an option to set the shorttcut in `Tools` > `Customize` > `Keyboard`

At the bottom of the Customize window choose **Insert** under `Category` and then choose **New Page** under `Function`. Then choose from the available **Shortcut Keys** that you can scroll through at the top of the `Customize` window. Once you've selected a keyboard shortcut you want click <kbd>Modify</kbd> over on the right and your keyboard shortcut will be set.

[image]

Comment: **New Page**?? I was looking for **New Slide**! That appears to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no default shortcut for that but the following method would be helpful:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> moves to the next text object on the slide. If there are no text objects on the slide, or if you reached the last text object, a new slide is inserted after the current slide.